# how to prove $\sum_{j=\frac{k}{2}+1}^{k-1}\binom{k-1}{j}\binom{n-(k-1)}{k-j}<2\binom{n-1}{k-1}$?

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, binomial-coefficients

I want to prove for $2\le k<n$ (and $k$ is even if necessary)

$$\sum_{j=\frac{k}{2}+1}^{k-1}\binom{k-1}{j}\binom{n-(k-1)}{k-j}<2\binom{n-1}{k-1}.$$

MATLAB verifies it is true when $n=30$ and $k=10$. So I tend to believe in some range the inequality is true. Maybe some combinatorial proof will provide the range.

Comment: What do you mean by setting $(n,k) = (30,10)$ ? Are you interested in this particular case or in general ?

Comment: A proof of general case is better. While I think a proof of the special case should already be informative.

Comment: We have $LHS<\frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ so the inequality always hold for $\frac{n}{2}\leq k \leq n$. The remaining interval still needs to be proved